# Python circle - moves and detects obstacles (moves alone, not with arrows)

Tags: python, tkinter, collision-detection

I want to make a circle move and avoid obstacles with collision detection. Here's the code I have.

```
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window,width=800, height=500, bg='pink')
canvas.pack()
finishline = canvas.create_oval(700, 300, 700+50, 300+50,fill='green')
robot = canvas.create_oval(20,200,20+45,200+45,fill='yellow')#(x1, y1, x2, y2)
ob1 = canvas.create_rectangle(200,400,200+50,200+1,fill='black')
canvas.update()
ob1 = canvas.create_rectangle(500,200,150+400,300+100,fill='blue')
canvas.update()
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I want to make the circle move and avoid obstacles with collision detection.

Comment: see [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the canvas.find_overlapping method (found here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method), and if it ever returns a value other than your own little circle, you can make the circle go in the other direction or something.

It's kind of hard to give a specific answer with such unspecific requirements.